# Sentence structure "What is common to [..] is that"

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sentence-patterns

> **What is common to** all these types of services **is that** the process of their delivery is subject to our internal control of quality.

I am not sure about the sentence structure indicated above. I wonder whether this structure is unusual for native speakers of English? Google does not clear up this question.

Here I am speaking about the common feature of the services.

Comment: It's grammatical, but very complex. It's a _Wh_-cleft construction related to _[That the process of their delivery is subject to our internal control of quality] is common to all these types of services_. The bracketed portion is a tensed subject complement clause, which is the subject of _is common_. This is already too complex to parse easily, and applying the _Wh_-cleft rule usually is an attempt to clarify. I wouldn't say it was clarified much, though. If it's important, use shorter sentences and phrases (e.g, _quality control_) and don't be afraid to repeat yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It reads like corporate-speak [all it really means is 'we don't screw up'] but grammatically it's absolutely fine.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a native speakers of English I am afraid. I, however, will write " what is common to all these types of services is that the process of their delivery is subject to our internal [quality control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_control) ."

Or

" What is common to all these types of services is their delivery is subject to our internal [quality control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_control) ."

Answer (score 0):

What is unusual about this sentence and those like it is that they are verbose and jargon-ridden. There is, however, nothing wrong with the grammar.

Comment: Nor is being verbose and jargon-ridden an unusual feature. Most written English is verbose and jargon-ridden.

Answer (score 0):

You could try re-phrasing it to see what it means:

> The common feature of these services is they are governed by our internal quality controls.

which proves that nine of the words in your original sentence are redundant.

Comment: But it is important to emphasize that when the services _are rendered_ they are subject to quality control at the same time. Control is exercised in the process of rendering the services.

Comment: @Amandedouce: You can't expect one sentence to give facts and emphasis both. If you want to emphasize something, put it in a different sentence instead of trusting in implication or presupposition.